# How do I blend the functions of isAuthorized and Auth->allow/deny into one method in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, authentication

In my design, an action has a rank, 0-10 required to access it (0 being a guest [not logged in], 10 being an admin).  Each user has a rank, 0-10.  If you have the rank or higher, you can access the action, otherwise you can't.  Nice and simple, it's all I need.

The problem is that CakePHP wants me to treat actions with two separate concepts.  I have to mark them Auth->allow/deny to determine if the auth system even bothers with them, and then I control access to them with isAuthorized().

isAuthorized works great for my needs... except that any action I want to have access of rank 0 to has to be Auth->allow()... which then ignores my isAuthorized method completely.  If I deny all the pages, the login triggers on the pages that should be rank 0, before it checks isAuthorized, so even if I grant authorization through it, the person has to log in first.

Is there any way to merge the two systems together, or a simple way to replace it?  Most of the auth system is great, and takes care of business for me without me having to mess with it... but this is just awkward and is going to cause problems when I don't notice a mixed up allow/deny or something.

Thanks!

Comment: This is just a thought, but you could have a guest account with rank 0 and make it the current user when no user is logged in.

Comment: How do you map the level to an action?

Comment: dr Lecter - that sounds like a really promising idea.  So you're suggesting just forcing login to a guest account, rank 0, when they first arrive, and then leave the option available for login if they're at rank 0?  Any problems you can foresee off the top of your head I'll need to address?

Comment: Burzum - I've just been doing if ($this->action === 'xyz') or switches within the isAuthorized method.  Then I just call a method I wrote to check the ranks which returns true/false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I see it, the only way to do this is to create a guest user. This is because the Auth component checks the existence of a user before ever getting to `isAuthorized()` like you explained.

You can do this by writing directly to the session. This will tell the Auth component that someone is logged in, so your `isAuthorized()` method will be called.

**AppController**

```
public function beforeFilter() {
  // if no one is logged in, log in a guest
  if (!$this->Auth->user()) {
    $this->Session->write(AuthComponent::$sessionKey, array(
      'User' => array(
        'id' => 0
       )
    ));
  }
}

public function isAuthorized($user) {
  $authorized = false;
  if ($this->Auth->user('id') == 0) {
    // public guest user access
  }
  // other logic
  return $authorized;
}
```

A possibly better way to do this is to use a custom authentication object, which basically tells Cake to use that class to help authenticate. This splits the logic into a separate class, making it easier to test and even disable.

**app/Controller/Component/Auth/GuestAuthenticate.php**

```
App::uses('BaseAuthenticate', 'Controller/Component/Auth');

class GuestAuthenticate extends BaseAuthenticate {
    public function authenticate(CakeRequest $request, CakeResponse $response) {
        // no real authentication logic, just return a guest user
        return array('User' => array('id' => 0));
    }
}
```

**AppController**

```
public $components = array(
  'Auth' => array(
    'authenticate' => array(
      'Form',
      'Guest' // tell Cake to try Form authentication then Guest authentication
    )
  )
);

public function beforeFilter() {
  if (!$this->Auth->user()) {
    // no user? log in a guest (this will fail form authentication
    // then try guest authentication)
    $this->Auth->login();
  }
}

public function isAuthorized($user) {
  $authorized = false;
  if ($this->Auth->user('id') == 0) {
    // public guest user access
  }
  // other logic
  return $authorized;
}
```

You can find more information on custom authentication objects here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html

Comment: You're doing almost exactly what I would like to do.  But here's the problem: by default, the Auth system denies everything.  That means that you must first log in before it will even consider the isAuthorized method.  If I allow everything first, then all actions are made completely public and isAuthorized is ignored.  Basically everything works great with denying everything, except for guests visiting the site, because they're forced to register an account first before isAuthorized will be checked.

Comment: What do guests have access to? Generally it's just a couple of pages, right? In that case, `Auth::allow()` works perfectly. For example, `Auth::allow('*')` on the pages controller.

Comment: Well that in itself is the issue.  It's not going to be just a couple pages, they'll be able to access half the website without being logged in, with additional features if they are logged in.  I don't want to try to manage, in two different methods, if they have to be logged in or not and at one rank.  It makes way more sense to make that all one fluid system, so that if I decide a page needs to be changed from rank 0 to rank 1, I can just adjust one character... the other way is way too conducive for errors.  That's why I'd like to merge them together

Comment: Let me reexplain, I understand how the system works now.  I'm not asking how to use it as is, I'm asking in what way can I take the way CakePHP does it and merge those two concepts together.

Comment: Then it sounds like ACL might be the way to go. It's more complicated to implement but would work really well in this situation. That's another topic, though.

Comment: No... I'm afraid I disagree.  You still have to mark pages with Auth::allow in order to view them without first logging in, and doing so bypasses ACL authentication... and if you deny all, it's going to require a log in before you can ever touch the ACL checks.  That puts me right back in the exact same problem as this one, just using a different system (and makes it even more likely that I'll make an error, since they wont be on the same page).  Besides, it defeats the purpose... I don't need ACL, I'm happy with controller authentication, I just want to meld allow and isAuthorized together.

Comment: Ah, I think I'm understanding better now. The only way I see around it is to create a guest user (that is, a "public guest" user - maybe not the same as your 0 level guest) in the session *or* creating a custom authentication object that handles this. I can expand my answer to either one if you like.

Comment: Actually, I'd love to hear thoughts on both.  How would you suggest I go about each?

Comment: The more I looked into it, the only way is to create a guest user (or maybe detach the Auth component at runtime but that seems like it could cause trouble). I outlined my suggestions for going about this. I was looking at stateless authentication do do it without a guest user, but it takes precedence over the session so an actual logged in user would still be seen as guest, which is a bummer.

Comment: It's looking pretty good, I have another project I have to wrap up tonight since it's deadline is tomorrow and then I'm going to resume this.  Thank you for your feedback!

Comment: Jumping from your suggestion, would it be possible for me to create a default user based on my user model using something like GuestAuthenticate?  I'm wondering if I set my default values for the fields in the model, could I just generate a new object using User to get a default "guest," so that it would have all the properties my user model should have?  I'm newer to CakePHP, so I thought I should run this by you before I bother attempting the code

Comment: There might not be a need for that, since all you need to do is make the auth component aware that someone is logged in in order to get to `isAuthorized()` and id is sufficient. There's no need for the guest to have a group, name, or anything, let alone be stored in the db (if you were suggesting that).

Comment: No need, perhaps, but I thought I might make extended use out of it if I'm going to do it anyway!  I'd rather not store it in the DB... I'd like to avoid that in case I clear the db and forget about it or what have you

Comment: The authentication classes are really meant for more advanced things, like authenticating with other apis, etc. But I think for this purpose it splits things up nicely. Easier to test, too :)

Comment: Thanks so much for your help Jeremy, you absolutely nailed the issue and gave me the perfect (and I really mean perfect) solution for creating a default guest account.  Bug testing now, but with a few small changes and adaptions, it's working exactly how I imagined, thanks to your information on my multiple questions!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this has already been dealt with satisfactorily but I have a solution.

In my AppController I have the following:

```
    public function isAuthorized($user = null) {
        if (in_array($this->action, $this->Auth->allowedActions)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

As you've found, if you don't explicitly authorize actions, they are denied to authenticated users, even if they are allowed to the public. This snippet of code just makes the isAuthorized() method honour the settings in the Auth->allow() list.

It seems to work for me, so I hope it helps.

Comment: That's another good solution to the issue.  I have found that the solution posted above works best for my situation, but I think this is a great solution to make note of.